# How can I change the Locale in the default browser?

Tags: browser, languages, localization

I have a Nexus One with Android 2.3.3 and I use the default browser. My phone doesn't have "Swedish" as language setting, so I use English. But now when I use Google, I'm not redirected to the Swedish edition (google.se), probably because the browser doesn't use a Swedish locale. Is there any way I can change the locale for the browser? I have looked in the settings but couldn't find it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the google website homepage itself in your browser, scroll down to were it says:

**iGoogle Settings Help**

press 'settings'

and turn off 'allow use of device location'

I have then found my browser always goes to google.com (were it was going to google.de)

*EDIT*

I've just seen you want the opposite. So perhaps turn this option **on**!

Comment: I'm sure for the android browser the locale is done on Googles side. Are you signed into google? I would set the location like I said. If your in sweden and the site is a good one you should get .se :-)